# How do I import Twilio in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, twilio-php

How do I import the Twilio library in Laravel Controller?

I tried several ways of importing in but it does not work

```
FatalErrorException in TwilioController.php line 13:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Services_Twilio' not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to install via composer? The [docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/php/install) seem pretty straight forward.

`composer require twilio/sdk`

Then you'd initiate the Twilio class in your app. Like so:

```
$client = new \Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);
```

Because Laravel is uses namespaces, you'll need to make sure the class reference is pointed to the correct namespace. By adding the `\` before `Services_Twilio` you are referencing the global namespace. You can also use a `use` statement at the top of your file to reference the Twilio class, so you don't need the `\`. Here is a good [reference on namespaces](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/php-namespaces-in-120-seconds)

Comment: How do I initiate the class? I installed via Composer already

Comment: Thanks for the update information in your question, I've updated my answer too.